# How to multiply diagonal elements by each other using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For the purpose of this exercise, let's consider a matrix where the element `m_{i, j}` is given by the rule `m_{i, j} = i*j` if `i == j` and `0` else.

Is there an easy "numpy" way of calculating such a matrix without having to resort to `if` statements checking for the indices?

Comment: `m = np.diag(np.square(np.arange(N)))`, for a `NxN` matrix?

Comment: What do you mean under *calculating such a matrix*? Title suggest that you want product of all elements placed on diagonal, however `matrix-multiplication` tag suggest you want multiplying matrix by matrix. Please add if possible simple example with matrix and desired output.

Comment: Sorry for using confusing tags... initially i had the thought that a possible approach involved matrix multiplication.. i believe it should be clear what the matrix would look like given the above description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the numpy function `diag` to construct a diagonal matrix if you give it the intended diagonal as a 1D array as input.

So you just need to create that, like `[i**2 for i in range (N)]` with `N` the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: I guess that's the solution I like most because it gives the option to operate on the indeces within the list comprehension if needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a squared matrix, you can do this:

```py
import numpy as np

ary = np.zeros((4, 4))
_ = [ary.__setitem__((i, i), i**2) for i in range(ary.shape[0])]
print(ary)
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 4., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 9.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the identity matrix given by `numpy.identity(n)` and then multiply it by a `n` dimensional vector.